# SQL - Summarise single column in result set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, aggregate

I currently have the following query in SQL Server 2012. A single row is returned for fields except 'cd.billed_amt as [Disb Billed]', which can have multiple results for a single bill_num.

What I’d like to do is summarise only the [Disb Billed] column, so that the initial 8 line result set will become a 2 line result set.

```
select distinct bbl.bill_num, 
       bb.tran_type, 
       hm.clnt_matt_code, 
       bb.tran_date, 
       bb.period, 
       cd.billed_amt as [Disb Billed], 
       fees_amt
  from blt_bill_amt bb
  join hbm_matter hm on bb.matter_uno = hm.matter_uno
  join blt_billm bbm on bbm.billm_uno = bb.billm_uno
  join blt_bill bbl on bbl.tran_uno = bbm.bill_tran_uno
  left outer join cdt_disb cd on cd.bill_tran_uno = bbl.tran_uno
 where bb.tran_type in ('WO', 'WOX') 
  and bb.period = '201401'
  and bbl.bill_num = 231728
order by  bb.tran_type, bbl.bill_num
```

Current result set

```
bill_num tran_type clnt_matt_code       tran_date                period   Disb Billed   fees_amt
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
231728   WO         N10118.1016         2013-04-18 00:00:00.000  201401   3.00          8.06
231728   WO         N10118.1016         2013-04-18 00:00:00.000  201401   20.00         8.06
231728   WO         N10118.1016         2013-04-18 00:00:00.000  201401   38.00         8.06
231728   WO         N10118.1016         2013-04-18 00:00:00.000  201401   42.50         8.06
231728   WO         N10118.1016-0001    2013-04-18 00:00:00.000  201401   3.00          0.94
231728   WO         N10118.1016-0001    2013-04-18 00:00:00.000  201401   20.00         0.94
231728   WO         N10118.1016-0001    2013-04-18 00:00:00.000  201401   38.00         0.94
231728   WO         N10118.1016-0001    2013-04-18 00:00:00.000  201401   42.50         0.94
```

Desired result set

```
bill_num tran_type clnt_matt_code       tran_date                period   Disb Billed   fees_amt
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
231728   WO         N10118.1016         2013-04-18 00:00:00.000  201401   103.50        8.06
231728   WO         N10118.1016-0001    2013-04-18 00:00:00.000  201401   103.50        0.94
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group your results using GROUP BY [reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

So for your example:

```
select distinct bbl.bill_num, 
       bb.tran_type, 
       hm.clnt_matt_code, 
       bb.tran_date, 
       bb.period, 
       SUM(cd.billed_amt) as [Disb Billed], --sum the billed column
       fees_amt
  from blt_bill_amt bb
  join hbm_matter hm on bb.matter_uno = hm.matter_uno
  join blt_billm bbm on bbm.billm_uno = bb.billm_uno
  join blt_bill bbl on bbl.tran_uno = bbm.bill_tran_uno
  left outer join cdt_disb cd on cd.bill_tran_uno = bbl.tran_uno
 where bb.tran_type in ('WO', 'WOX') 
  and bb.period = '201401'
  and bbl.bill_num = 231728
GROUP BY bbl.bill_num, --add group by
       bb.tran_type, 
       hm.clnt_matt_code, 
       bb.tran_date, 
       bb.period,
       fees_amt
order by  bb.tran_type, bbl.bill_num
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, exactly what I was trying to do.